# com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.defaulthttpdatasource.makeconnection - Can not open connection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I work in an audio player android application using Kotlin and ExoPlayer and Firebase Cloud Firestore to save songs and retrieve them. I face these errors :

> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.defaulthttpdatasource.makeconnection & java.net.malformedurlexception: unknown protocol: gs

And I understand the android can not open the connection - so how can I fix this problem I tried many many of solutions .its doesn't work unfortunately

I have internet permission and I mentioned the service in manifest .also doesn't work

- I have internet permission
- I mentioned the service in manifest.also doesn't work
- xml internet config
- android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" cleartext to avoid HTTP connection

Comment: Where are you saving the audio files, in Firebase Storage? Show us an example of an URL of an audio file.

Comment: this the folder bath : - " gs://spotify-clone-pl-7c33f.appspot.com/ " and i would like to know how to getnthis url from android studio coz i retrive the list of music when i want click on it to play i get this error

Answer (score 1):

URLs that start with "gs://" are basically Google Cloud Storage native URLs. Unfortunately, these types of URLs are not recognized by many libraries, including ExoPlayer.

To be able to play those songs, you have two options. You either [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) for the audio file (which starts with "https://"), and you pass it to ExoPlayer, or you [download the audio file from Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_files) through the Firebase SDK, and then pass the local file to ExoPlayer.

Comment: Hey Hassan. Have you tried my solutions above, does it work?

Comment: Hello, Alex thank you very much for your solution, it was very clear and useful it's my pleasure to work with your solution, but unfortunately, I will change my plan.

Comment: Can I help you with other information?